# Float to Real48

Tags: python, pascal

I am trying to convert a floating number to Real48 (Borland Pascal) in python. I have found this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908715/c-sharp-double-to-real) written i C# (I think)

```
static byte[] DoubleToReal48(double d)
{
  byte[] r = new byte[6];

  long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(d);
  bool negative = ((bits >> 63) & 1) != 0;
  long exponent = ((bits >> 52) & 0x7FF) - 1023;
  long mantissa = bits & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFL;

  long raw = (negative ? 1 : 0);
  raw = (raw << 39) | (mantissa >> 13);
  raw = (raw << 8) | ((exponent + 129) & 0xFF);

  for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
  {
    r[k] = (byte)(raw & 0xFF);
    raw >>= 8;
  }
  return r;
}
```

I don't know C#, so I'm having a hard time translating it to python. Can anyone help me? Or perhaps there is a better way?

I have found [this](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/251383/) but it seems to only convert Real48 to double, not the other way around as I need.

Comment: How do you hope to translate a type conversion to a language with dynamic typing where your target type doesn't exist?

Comment: So you're saying it can't be done?

Comment: Not necessarily, just that there's no `Real48` in Python, so whatever you do is contingent on what a `Real48` looks like to you in Python. Will you define your own class to store them? Do you have a library that will?

Comment: That is to say, there's no point in attempting to contain a Real48 in Python itself. Are you trying to serialize data for subsequent loading in a legacy Pascal program?

Comment: Yes - we have an old piece of data processing software that loads a log file (from data logger). The format is a "string" of 14 byte, first 1-8 byte is the date in TDataTime and 9-14 is the value in real48. Our new logging system write a csv file of the log. I am trying to see if I and translate the new csv log into the old format, so we can still use our data processing software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try to translate the C# to python

1.- Convert the bits from a double number to a number (unsigned long long).

```
long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(d);
```

translates to

```
struct.unpack("Q", struct.pack("d", python_double) )[0]
```

it uses the [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module from standard library.

2.- Extract each field from the double representation

```
bool negative = ((bits >> 63) & 1) != 0;
long exponent = ((bits >> 52) & 0x7FF) - 1023;
long mantissa = bits & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFL;
```

That can translated alsmot verbatim, since the same operators exist in python.

```
negative = ((bits >> 63) & 1)    # Integer 1 for negative, 0 for positive
exponent = ((bits >> 52) & 0x7FF) - 1023
mantissa = bits & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

3.- Pack again the number into 48 bits

```
long raw = (negative ? 1 : 0);
raw = (raw << 39) | (mantissa >> 13);
raw = (raw << 8) | ((exponent + 129) & 0xFF);
```

Same as number 2,

```
raw = negative
raw = (raw << 39) | (mantissa >> 13)
raw = (raw << 8) | ((exponent + 129) & 0xFF)
```

4.- Convert the number to a string of 6 bytes

```
for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
{
  r[k] = (byte)(raw & 0xFF);
  raw >>= 8;
}
```

Use struck as in step 1,

```
data = struck.pack('Q', raw)
data = data[:6]  # Drop the 16 MSB
```

NOTE: I'm dropping the last 2 chars because struct uses the processors' endianness by default (x86 in my case), but that can be controled with the first argument.

TIP: If you want to convert a number to a binary representation you could use `'{:064b}'.format(number)`. This will pad it with zeros to fill 64 chars.

Comment: Thank you so much - I get a syntax error at `mantissa = bits & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFL`. I am using python 3.4.

Comment: The trailing `L` in the numeric literal must be removed, I assumed python 2.

Comment: Thank you.. You saved my weekend:-)